# How do I to fix "Command txs:///pdflatex not defined" error from a fresh install of linux mint?

Tags: texstudio

I installed texstudio and received the following after compling my first document:

```
"Command txs:///pdflatex not defined"
```

I then installed texlive and received the following error after complying my document a second  time:

```
"Command txs:///pdflatex not defined"
```

Am I supposed to reinstall texstudio, or should I try something else?

How do I to fix "Command txs:///pdflatex not defined" error from a fresh install of linux mint?

Comment: Did you install TeX Live?

Comment: @egreg I think so, the terminal said texlivebinary...something like that. I am currently away from my computer at the moment.

Comment: Can you try compiling the document from the command line? That is, `pdflatex <filename>.tex` or whatever?